# SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied - Cannot send mail via Java - Even if SMTP is enabled at Outlook

Tags: java, email, outlook, smtp

I have this Java code. The Java code handels mail sending only via Outlook. This example is a minimal working example. Notice that it's NOT Office 365. It's regular Outlook.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MailConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${configuration.MailConfiguration.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${configuration.MailConfiguration.port}")
    private int port;
    @Value("${configuration.MailConfiguration.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${configuration.MailConfiguration.password}")
    private String password;
    
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {

        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();       
        mailSender.setHost(host);
        mailSender.setPort(port);
        mailSender.setUsername(username);
        mailSender.setPassword(password);
         
        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
         
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

And I send a message like this. Here `email = myMail@outlook.com` and `subject` is just a string.

```
    // Send message
    SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
    msg.setTo(email);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setText("Message: " + message +"\nCause: " + cause);
    try {
        javaMailSender.send(msg);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        // Something went wrong
    }
```

When I run the code above, I get this error. I'm trying to understand why.

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 HE1PR0701CA0065.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 25 Dec 2020 01:56:03 +0000
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587
EHLO dell-Precision-M6400
250-HE1PR0701CA0065.outlook.office365.com Hello [213.89.50.140]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
EHLO dell-Precision-M6400
250-HE1PR0701CA0065.outlook.office365.com Hello [213.89.50.140]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN XOAUTH2"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.office365.com, user=myMail@outlook.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<dell@dell-Precision-M6400>
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
RCPT TO:<myMail@outlook.com>
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   myMail@outlook.com
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Date: Fri, 25 Dec 2020 02:56:05 +0100 (CET)
To: myMail@outlook.com
Message-ID: <783908570.5.1608861365004@dell-Precision-M6400>
Subject: Alarm Message Subject Title
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Message: hejehej
Cause: Mesurement exceeded the threshold at analog input 0.
.
554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 

RSET
250 2.0.0 Resetting
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2373)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:2095)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:465)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:323)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:312)
    at se.danielmartensson.service.MailService.sendMessage(MailService.java:44)
    at se.danielmartensson.threads.SamplingThread.run(SamplingThread.java:227)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

I have enabled POP and IMAP at Outlook. But still, I cannot send. As you can see, I can login `DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded`.

But why does this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a login/sender related issue.

> `554 5.2.0` **`SendAsDenied`**
>
> **You are trying to send a mail with a sender different from your outlook login address.**

In your case, your login is one and the `MAILFROM` you're trying to send is a different one:

**`MAIL FROM`**`--> dell@dell-Precision-M6400`

**`LOGIN`**    `--> myMail@outlook.com`

So **`SendAs`**`(dell@dell-Precision-M6400)`**`Denied`** is thrown.

To make a simple test, try sending the same message but with your outlook credentials set as `MAILFROM`. It should work without errors.

In order to set different valid senders, **add the new sender in the outlook admin panel**. That would avoid the exception if trying to send the email with a different sender than your login.

Comment: But MAIL FROM is my Linux computer.

Comment: But your outlook login is a different one, right? Which is the username when you initialize the sender - mailSender.setUsername(username); ?

Comment: I solved this by setting `username` as the same as `msg.setFrom(from);` :)

Comment: I was intrigued, glad you could fix it. Have a nice day mate : )